# Access email notification in native ios app

Tags: ios, notifications

My application has requirement where based on email notification, I have to implement certain functionality.

Is there any way so that I can access email notification?

Thanks for help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It is much easier to get an answer if people notice that you did some research before posting a question.